# how to check an inline function was automatically converted to a regular function by the compiler?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

I know in some cases, the explicitly defined inline function will be converted to the regular function with calling stacks by the compiler. By how do I know this is the case? (for my C++ code)

BTW, in what circumstances will the compiler transform an inline function to a regular function?

Comment: _'in what circumstances will the compiler transform an inline function to a regular function'_ IMHO this is a question of the particular optimization level you're using to compile and the specific compiler implementation in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You run `nm` or `otool` on the executable, and if you see the name of the function, then it has been defined. That doesn't mean that it hasn't indeed been inlined at all (it's possible that the compiler inlines a function but also generates an independent function body because for example one assigns a function pointer to it). For that, you need to examine the actual generated assembly code.

Comment: Checking for the symbol won't help. Many compilers will generate an out-of-line definition of the function even when it is actually inlined.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Excuse me, but did you read the rest of my answer? "That doesn't mean that it hasn't indeed been inlined at all (it's possible that the compiler inlines a function but also generates an independent function body because for example one assigns a function pointer to it). For that, you need to examine the actual generated assembly code."

Comment: @H2CO3 So `nm` tells you exactly nothing. In my tests, even with high optimisation levels, the symbol was always defined, regardless of whether or not function calls were inlined.

Comment: Some compilers generate a `map` file containing all the symbols.  This is useful for platforms that don't have `nm` or `otool`.  The map file can be search by text editors or OS tools.

Comment: Yes, H2CO3, I read it. Maybe I was not clear enough that this is just a detail: there does not need to be a reason to generate the out-of-line symbol. Gcc, for example *always* generates it.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas OK, sorry, I didn't mean to be harsh. For correctness, I intentionally wrote "if you see the name of the function, then it has been defined" and **not** "if you see the name of the function, then it hasn't been inlined", because of course that wouldn't have been true.

Answer (score 2):

The keyword `inline` does not mean that the function will be inlined (or not). It means *allow for multiple definitions in different translation units of the same program*. The compiler will not transform an *inline* into a non-inline, it will follow the rules set in the standard and (almost) orthogonally determine whether to inline or not your functions.

As of whether to determine if a function was inlined or not, the guaranteed way to do so is checking the generated object code (or assembly). Checking whether there is an out-of-line definition of the function won't help, as many compilers will generate that out-of-line definition even if the code was actually inlined.

Comment: +1 for checking the assembly language.  This will tell if the function was inlined or the compiler generated a branch (call) to the function.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler will DEFINITELY produce a regular function if the inline function has it's address taken (that is, you are making a function pointer to it, or something similar). And of course, if the function is `virtual`, it also has to exist as a standalone function since a `virtual` function call is not always possible to inline.

Other than that, it's entirely up to the compiler - it uses all manner of heuristics, such as "How big is the function?", "how many times is it called?", "how much 'gain' is there from inlining it?". If a function is called many times, and is quite large, it is probably left as a standalone function. If the function is only called a few times, or it's tiny, then it's inlined [assuming the compiler actually CAN inline it, of course - as described above, it may not be able to]. Also, nearly all compilers need to "see" the source code of the function to inline the function, but both GCC/G++ and MSVC do have otions for "whole program optimisation" that is intended to overcome this issue.

In other words, you can only "know" by reading the resulting machine code - in some cases, there are also extended "warning" or "notes" messages that you can enable to tell the compiler to give you information about "I did not inline function `Func1` because ...insert some reason here...".